# How to prove that if $\lambda_{\max}(A)\leq t\quad\iff\quad A\preceq tI$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

where $\lambda_{\max}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A,$ and $A$ is symmetric.

$A\preceq tI$ means that $(tI-A)$ is positive semidefinite.

What would be approach for this?

First thought I had was to go with eignedecomposition, but don't see how this would lead to anything.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is not a free homework-solving service. Linear Algebra solutions cost 10$\$$ per each problem, with an additional cost of 4.99$ for same-day-service. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Hint: Prove the first implication $A \preceq tI \Rightarrow \lambda_{\max}(A) \leq t$. What does it mean for $tI - A$ to be positive semidefinite? (start from the definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out proof goes as following:

Using eigendecomposition of $A$: $A=Q\Lambda Q^\top\quad\Rightarrow\quad(tI-A)=Q(tI-\Lambda)Q^\top\quad \Rightarrow$
$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^m:\quad x^\top(tI-A)x=x^\top Q(tI-\Lambda)Q^\top x=\quad\big|\; y:= Q^\top x \;\big|\quad =y^\top(tI-\Lambda)y=\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(t-\lambda_i(A))y_i^2}\geq 0,\quad \mathrm{since}\; t\geq \lambda_{\max}(A),\quad\therefore\quad tI-A\succeq 0\quad\iff\quad A\preceq tI$

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong. Note that 
$$ A := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
has $\lambda_\max(A) = 1$, but 
$$ \def\I{\operatorname{Id}}\I - A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
is not semi-definite, as 
$$ \left<(\I - A)\binom 11,\binom 11\right> = -1 < 0 $$

Comment: Would this be true for symmetric $A$?

Comment: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not symmetric